# Haskell bitwise operators in Data.Bits

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation

I am new to Haskell and am trying to use bitwise operations from Data.Bits.  Every time I try I get an error message

```
Prelude Data.Bits> 1 `shiftL` 16

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraint:
      `Bits t' arising from a use of `shiftL' at <interactive>:1:0-12
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

This happens for a number of operations, I also tried .|. and .&.

I must be missing something very simple, please let me know if you can spot the problem

Comment: Can you post your ghc version? `GHCi, version 7.0.4` works fine. `ghci> 1 \`shiftL\` 16
-- output
65536`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the interactive session, Haskell can't infer the types of 1 and 16. The solution then, is to give a hint:

```
> :m +Data.Bits
> let a = 1 :: Int
> let b = 16 :: Int
> a `shiftL` b
65535
>
```

Comment: It *can* infer the type of 16, since `shiftL :: Bits a => a -> Int -> a`. Only the 1 is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  I also discovered that if I declare the function and specify all types explicitly that works too

Answer (score 3):

ghci doesn't know what type to choose. However, that shouldn't be so:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> 1 `shiftL` 16
65536
```

From the expression entered at the prompt, the constraint `Bits t` is inferred (also `Num t`, but `Num` is a superclass of `Bits`, hence implied; and since it is to be displayed by the interpreter, also `Show t`).

Now, since one of the constraints is a numeric class and all of the classes are defined in the Prelude or the standard libraries, the ambiguous type variable `t` is eligible for [defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4). In the absence of explicit default declarations, the ambiguity is resolved by choosing `Integer` as the type.

Off the top of my head, I can't think of a language extension that would prevent the resolution of the ambiguity by defaulting, so the conclusion is that your ghci is old. The `Bits` class was not in the standard libraries as defined by the Haskell98 report, so a `Bits` constraint was not eligible for defaulting in compilers adhering to that standard, for example GHC < 7.

In that case, the immediate workaround is to specify a type signature,

```
Prelude Data.Bits> 1 `shiftL` 16 :: Int
65536
```

and the fix to your problem is to upgrade your GHC to a version adhering to the newer Haskell2010 standard.

Comment: I think it's just about possible that this is not standards adherence but an arguable bug in ghc – there is a `Num` constraint arising from the numeric literal, which should make it eligible for ghci's [extended defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) – however the `Bits` constraint swallows the `Num` constraint, so it fails to default. Seems like newer GHCs don't have the problem, though.

Comment: I'l try to build the latest and see what happens.

Comment: Just built GHC and GHCI from source the bug appears to have been fixed